# How to configure Google autoML Translation Model in a CAT (Computer Aided Translation) tool?

Tags: google-cloud-automl

I created an AutoML Translation Model. Now OmegaT (my CAT tool), in which I use a Google API Key, only returns 403: Forbidden error.

I could not configured the model in OmegaT. I looked into the OmegaT User Manual and in the web without any luck!

Does someone have a clue in configuring the Google autoML Translation Model in a a CAT?

The Google API Translation was working alright before I created the model. I did research the web and everywhere else I knew (User Manual, web, Google Cloud, etc.) without any luck.

There is no code for sharing

The expected result was a better translation performance than with the Google NMT Model per se.
The actual result received was: 403: Forbidden

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you've already found the answer to this question, but I believe that most CAT tools currently don't support use of Google AutoML customized MT systems. From what I've read, Memsource is the only one that currently does. MemoQ is scheduled to develop a connector with it soon. 
The only way I've been able to do batch translation with an AutoML model is by creating a separate Python tool. This doesn't help with CAT tool integration though.

Comment: Sorry for the time i took to make this comment.

Comment: I am using "OmegaT" an i was finally able to configure it for using the automl API.